# Calling generic method in Java: cannot convert Type to generic parameter T

Tags: java, generics

I'm coming from C# world and I'm having troubles using generics in Java. For some reason, Java complains about not being able to convert my types. Here's my code

```
public <T1, T2> ArrayList<T2> convert(List<T1> list, Function<T1, T2> function) {
            ArrayList<T2> result = new ArrayList<T2>();
            for (T1 source : list) {
                T2 output = function.apply(source);
                result.add(output);
            }
            return result;
        }

public SomeType convertSomeType(SourceType input){
    .....
    return ....
}
```

and call it something like:

```
List<SourceType> list...
SomeType result = convert(list, this::convertSomeType)
```

I get Bad return type in method reference. Cannot convert SomeType to T2.

I also tried specifying generic parameters like so:
List list...
    SomeType result = convert(list, this::convertSomeType)

but it didn't help. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What's `Tm`? Did you mean `T2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method returns an `ArrayList<T2>` (I'm assuming `Tm` is a typo), not `T2`:

```
// Your version, doesn't work:
SomeType result = convert(list, this::convertSomeType)

// This works:
List<SomeType> result = convert(list, this::convertSomeType)
```

Also, you should make that `convert()` method follow [PECS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2723397/521799):

```
public <T1, T2> ArrayList<T2> convert(
    List<? extends T1> list,
    Function<? super T1, ? extends T2> function
);
```

Comment: yes, you're so right! I found my mistake out right after posting it but thanks for you answer! However, the error message should have been clearer :)

Comment: @user5080246: Yes indeed, the Java compiler often puts a side-effect of the actual error in the error message, which can be very confusing when using method references or lambdas...